# Postgres Syntax error caused by dash ind CLI command

Tags: postgresql, bash, syntax-error

I have a script with this command

```bash
/usr/bin/psql postgres -h localhost -U postgres -c "GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE "famdb-develop" TO fullwood;"
```

When I ran it, I got this error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "-"
LINE 1: GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE famdb-develop TO fullwood;
```

How can I escape the dash in this command?

Comment: i think you need to escape the quotes around famdb-develop like \"famdb-develop\"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the quotes aren't being passed down to PostgreSQL. You need to escape them by prefixing them with backslashes (`\`):

```bash
/usr/bin/psql postgres -h localhost -U postgres -c "GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE \"famdb-develop\" TO fullwood;"
# Here -----------------------------------------------------------------------^--------------^
```

Answer (score 1):

As you don't have variables in your sql you could use single quotes

```
/usr/bin/psql postgres -h localhost -U postgres -c 'GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE "famdb-develop" TO fullwood;'
```